# Xcode 6.1 Swift issue - 'init()' is unavailable: superseded by import of -[NSObject init]

Tags: swift, ios8, scenekit, xcode6.1

I have just upgraded my Xcode to 6.1 an am now getting a strange compilation error.

> 'init()' is unavailable: superseded by import of -[NSObject init]

I am subclassing SCNNode and have a optional references to other classes of the same type I am defining. i.e.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

    class BayNode: SCNNode {

        var leftBay:BayNode?
        var rightBay:BayNode?


        func addLeftBay()
        {

            leftBay = BayNode()   // 'init()' is unavailable: superseded by import of -[NSObject init]

        }


    }
```

Does anybody know how I can resolve this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: it helps others (including SO's syntax highlighter) read your code if you follow Swift naming conventions, like naming types with initial caps. That is, use `BayNode`, not `bayNode`.

Comment: Hi Rickster, I will do next time ;-). I'm pretty new on here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have same problem, one way I found to suppress the error is to explicitly cast it:

```
leftBay = BayNode() as BayNode
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've tried this and works great. It performs as it did with Xcode 6.01. Does anybody know why, or can offer an explaination behind this change?

Comment: Probably a bug in type checking. [File it with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) to help make a speedy fix more likely.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a consequence of a move to stricter type checking within the language.

Comment: So it indeed was a bug, it's fixed in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta 2)

Comment: @Alex-alex I got the same error in Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7)