# 'init()' is unavailable xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I received the error

> 'init()' is unavailable

here :

```
 func download() {
    var assetResource = AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest()
}
```

and here:

```
let loader = AVAssetResourceLoader()
```

I tried to follow the recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571447/xcode-6-1-swift-issue-init-is-unavailable-superseded-by-import-of-nsobj), but the error remains. I'm using XCode 7 and Swift 2.

I made following and get the same error.

```
let loader = AVURLAsset().resourceLoader
```

Comment: You can't create those objects directly.  You can get the loader through the `resourceLoader` property on `AVURLAsset` and the loader creates the requests itself.

Comment: I wrote following code let loader = AVURLAsset().resourceLoader but I got the same error. @dan

Comment: You *have* to initialize the AVURLAsset with an URL.

Comment: @EricD. thank you. It helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url)
```